# Loop "for" pause bug

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I am making a discord bot in python, and I ran into a problem. I wanted to make a command that lists all the servers that have my bot. Everything went well, but as soon as there were more than 5 servers, there was a pause of 2-3 seconds between 5 servers. My code looked like this:

```
import discord
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.ext.commands import bot

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ";", intents=discord.Intents.all(),help_command=None,case_insensitive=True)

@bot.command()
async def listguilds(ctx):
    servers = bot.guilds
    for guild in servers:
        await ctx.send(guild.name)

bot.run(TOKEN)
```

Can I make it display the guild list without pauses?

Comment: I advise you to read this discord article on ratelimit: https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#rate-limits

You can't send as many requests to the api as you want in as little time.

Comment: Join the names first, then send it together (take account of the 4000 characters limit). You're currently sending too many requests and you're getting rate limited.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send one message per guild which is not a really great idea as you might get [rate-limited](https://discord.com/developers/docs/topics/rate-limits#rate-limits) and sending many messages in a short period of time, usually doesn't work well. I would suggest looping first, getting all guilds and after that sending a message:

```py
@bot.command()
async def listguilds(ctx):
    servers = bot.guilds
    all_guilds = "" #empty string which will store all guilds
    for guild in servers:
        all_guilds += guild.name + "\n"
    await ctx.send(all_guilds)
```

**or by using [embeds](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?#discord.Embed):**

```py
@bot.command()
async def listguilds(ctx):
    servers = bot.guilds
    embed = discord.Embed(color=discord.Color.blurple(), title="Guild list")
    for guild in servers:
        embed.add_field(name=guild.name, value=len(guild.members), inline=False) #also shows how many members are on server (requires intents.members!!!)
    await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```